# Ein schwieriges Komma

Tags: punctuation

Könnten Sie mir sagen bitte, ob dieses Komma richtig oder unrichtig ist? Welche Variante ist korrekt?

1. Was er schon getan hat **,** kann nicht rückgängig gemacht werden.
2. Was er schon getan hat kann nicht rückgängig gemacht werden.

Answer (score 2):

"Was er schon getan hat" ist ein Nebensatz, der hier gleichzeitig auch das Subjekt des Hauptsatzes ist. Dass es sich um einen Nebensatz handelt, kann man daran sehen, dass der Teil ein eigenes konjugiertes Verb ('getan hat') und ein eigenes Subjekt ('er') hat.

Nebensätze werden vom Hauptsatz immer durch Komma getrennt, @RHa hat die Regel dazu bereits in den Kommentaren verlinkt: [§74 des amtlichen Regelwerks](https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/rechtschreibung/6201).

Wenn der Nebensatz (wie dieser)  am Anfang oder Ende steht, wird er mit einem Komma vom Hauptsatz getrennt. In dem Fall, dass der Nebensatz (wie dieser) eingeschoben ist, wird er mit zwei Kommas am Anfang und am Ende abgegrenzt.

Richtig ist also:

> Was er schon getan hat, kann nicht rückgängig gemacht werden.

Answer (score -6):

Der Lesbarkeit halber wird in einem Fall wie dem beschriebenen im Allgemeinen ein Komma eingefügt. Allein nach streng grammatischen Gesichtspunkten betrachtet, braucht es das jedoch nicht.

*Was er schon getan hat* ist eine Nominalphrase, die im Satz die Position des Subjekts einnimmt und daher durch jede beliebige andere Nominalphrase ersetzt werden kann, also beispielsweise auch durch ein Pronomen wie *es*:

> Es kann nicht rückgängig gemacht werden.

Comment: Im Deutschen setzt man keine Kommas "für die Lesbarkeit" - Sondern nach festen Regeln. Hier gilt §74 der Rechtschreibregeln, und da wird ein Komma verlangt, da "Was er schon getan hat" ein Relativsatz ist (siehe gleich das erste Beispiel bei §74).

Comment: @tofro: es gibt - auch laut Rechtschreibregeln - *optionale* Kommata im Deutschen, die man setzen kann, wenn man der Meinung ist, daß das die Lesbarkeit unterstützt. Das ist hier nicht der Fall, aber das rundheraus in Abrede zu stellen, ist ebenfalls über das Ziel hinausgeschossen.

Comment: @bakunin Es gibt tatsächlich Sprachen, die setzen Satzzeichen "zur besseren Lesbarkeit" (z.B. Englisch). Deutsch ist keine davon. **Auch das erlaubte Setzen eines *optionalen Kommas* steht in einer Regel**, und wenn es das nicht tut, ist es nicht erlaubt.

Comment: @user56194, die Antwort ist nicht richtig. Siehe z.B. „[Das Komma, wenn der Nebensatz Subjekt ist](https://blog.leo.org/2019/12/10/das-komma-wenn-der-nebensatz-subjekt-ist/)“ auf dem Blog *Fragen Sie Dr. Bopp!*

Comment: @tofro: Auch wenn das erlaubte Setzen eines optionalen Kommas in einer Regel steht, so verbietet diese Regel nicht, sie zum Zwecke der besseren Lesbarkeit anzuwenden und ein Komma zu setzen. Ich habe nicht bestritten, daß es Regeln für optionale Kommata gibt, sondern lediglich, daß der Zweck der besseren Lesbarkeit generell unstatthaft wäre, was der Satz "im Deutschen setzt man keine Kommas für die Lesbarkeit" jedenfalls insinuiert. Man kann sie - auch - für die Lesbarkeit setzen, sofern eine Regel ein optionales Komma erlaubt.

Comment: @tofro Ein Komma dient immer der Lesbarkeit. [Rechtschreibrat](https://www.rechtschreibrat.com/DOX/sr11-extra.pdf): "Leitend bei der jeweiligen Entscheidung sollte die allgemeine Maxime sein, nach der Satzzeichen dazu dienen, den geschriebenen Text übersichtlich zu gestalten und ihn dadurch für den Lesenden überschaubar zu machen." (Seite 15) Falsch wird diese Antwort erst durch den zweiten Satz.